# Is there any fantasy backing to a viper turning into a magical horse, as shown in King's Quest II?

Tags: fantasy-genre, mythology, kings-quest-ii

In the original version of King's Quest II, there's a puzzle that involves throwing a leather bridle onto a viper and turning it into a magical horse, which King Graham then gets a poison-neutralizing sugar cube from. The inanity of the puzzle is nicely covered by this TV Tropes mention:

> Mercy Rewarded: Probably one of the most infuriating examples in the series — instead of killing the snake with the sword that has a snake pattern on it, you should throw the bridle on it, so it will turn into a flying horse that will give you a magic sugar cube that neutralizes poison, so you can pass through the poison thistle patch on the way to Dracula's castle.. - [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/KingsQuestIIRomancingTheThrone)

As near as I can tell there's no in-game hint that you can even throw the bridle onto a snake, let alone that the snake is actually a mystical talking horse that can cure poison. But one of the hooks of the King's Quest series is that it often borrows story beats and characters from popular fairy tales and fantasy movies with the expectation that the audience would know the story and be able to solve the puzzle that way. So it's very possible that the writers were borrowing from a fable that the audience was supposed to know about.

Is there any historical or literary source for a viper turning into a magic horse?

Comment: There is a weak connection between the most well-known winged horse, Pegasus, and snakes. Pegasus was born from the gorgon Medusa, who had snakes for hair. The story of Pegasus also includes a magic bridle used by the hero Bellerophon to ride him. I have no idea though if that was what Sierra wanted to refer to when they made the game.

Comment: In reality, back before there were internet walkthroughs, when we got stuck we just started brute force attacks on the game: “throw sword at snake. Throw apple at snake. Throw special key at snake. Throw bag at snake. Throw cheese at snake. Throw flower at snake. Throw bridle at snake…. Wait it was the *bridle*?? How are we supposed to have figured that out?”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Kings Quest Wiki entry for the Bridle](https://kingsquest.fandom.com/wiki/Bridle) mentions two possible sources:

> One Romanian fairy tale known as *The Fairy Aurora* (which appears in Andrew Lang's Violet Fairy book from Andrew Lang's Fairy Books, which he calls *The Fairy of the Dawn*), the Hero Petru is tasked with throwing a bridle over the head of several "Welwa" (a monsterous beast depending on the source, which is either similar to the ugly beast that becomes a unicorn seen in KQ8, or a giant worm/snake, of some sort). When he throws the bridle over each of the beasts head, each creature turns into a beautiful horse.
>
> An Irish fairy tale, *The Lady Witch* speaks of a witch that throws a magic bridle on a man and rides him all night. The King's Quest Companion alludes to this or a similar story as well, see above, and in witches.